# Onclick Image button is not working Asp.net Grid View

Tags: asp.net, gridview

In asp.net gridview i am using a image click but it is not working ?

```
<asp:GridView ID="GVPending" DataKeyNames="Userid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
  <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="#">
             <ItemTemplate>
                            <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
                        </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>

        <asp:BoundField DataField="Name" HeaderText="Name"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Branch" HeaderText="Branch"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Address" HeaderText="Address"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="EmailAddress" HeaderText="Email"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Phonenumber" HeaderText="Phone Number"></asp:BoundField>
     <asp:TemplateField>
             <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnEdit" runat="server" CommandName="Approve"  ImageUrl="~/approve.jpg" OnClick="btnEdit_Click"  ToolTip="Approve" style="
    width: 30px;
"/>
        <asp:ImageButton ID="btnDelete" runat="server" CommandName="Decline" ImageUrl="~/delete.jpg" OnClick="btnDelete_Click" ToolTip="Decline" style="
    width: 30px;
" />
    </ItemTemplate>
         </asp:TemplateField>
     </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

code :

```
protected void btnEdit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageButton lbtn = (ImageButton)sender;
            GridViewRow row = (GridViewRow)lbtn.NamingContainer;
            if (row != null)
            {
                string userid = Convert.ToString(GVPending.DataKeys[row.RowIndex].Value);
            }
        }
```

In this onclick is not firing.please go through the design and code that i submitted.If anyone help it will great to me

Comment: try using `RowItemCommand` of the `Grid` instead of using `btnEdit_Click`.

Comment: I tried your code, it works!
I think it goes wrong somewhere else in your code.